# Words in WordNet corpus clarification

Tags: nlp, nltk, wordnet, nltk-book

I want to get the length of words in the `WordNet` corpus

**Code:**

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

len_wn = len([word.lower() for word in wn.words()])
print(len_wn)
```

I get the output as `147306`

**My Questions:**

- Am I getting the total length of words in `WordNet`?
- Does `tokens` such as `zoom_in` counts as `word`?

Comment: Try printing out what's in `wn.words()`

Comment: @alvas this question is not a duplicate - I am looking to check if I am on the right approach to get the total length of `wordnet`, not find if a `word` is in the `wordnet`, which is where you pointed this question as duplicate :)

Comment: printing out `wn.words()` and looking at them helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

## **Am I getting the total length of words in WordNet?**

Depends on what is the definition of "words". The `wn.words()` function iterate through all the `lemma_names`, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1701 and https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1191

```
def words(self, lang="eng"):
    """return lemmas of the given language as list of words"""
    return self.all_lemma_names(lang=lang)


def all_lemma_names(self, pos=None, lang="eng"):
    """Return all lemma names for all synsets for the given
    part of speech tag and language or languages. If pos is
    not specified, all synsets for all parts of speech will
    be used."""

    if lang == "eng":
        if pos is None:
            return iter(self._lemma_pos_offset_map)
        else:
            return (
                lemma
                for lemma in self._lemma_pos_offset_map
                if pos in self._lemma_pos_offset_map[lemma]
            )
```

So if the definition of "words" is all the possible lemma, then yes, this function gives you the total length of words in the lemma names in Wordnet:

```
>>> sum(len(lemma_name) for lemma_name in wn.words())
1692291
>>> sum(len(lemma_name.lower()) for lemma_name in wn.words())
1692291
```

Lowercasing is not necessary because lemma names should have came lowered. Even named entities, e.g.

```
>>> 'new_york' in wn.words()
True
```

But do note that the same lemma can have very similar lemma names:

```
>>> 'new_york' in wn.words()
True
>>> 'new_york_city' in wn.words()
True
```

That's because of how wordnet is structured. The API in NLTK organizes "meaning" as synset, a synset contains is linked to multiple lemmas and each lemma comes with at least one name:

```
>>> wn.synset('new_york.n.1')
Synset('new_york.n.01')

>>> wn.synset('new_york.n.1').lemmas()
[Lemma('new_york.n.01.New_York'), Lemma('new_york.n.01.New_York_City'), Lemma('new_york.n.01.Greater_New_York')]

>>> wn.synset('new_york.n.1').lemma_names()
['New_York', 'New_York_City', 'Greater_New_York']
```

But each "word" you query can have multiple synsets (i.e. multiple meaning), e.g.

```
>>> wn.synsets('new_york')
[Synset('new_york.n.01'), Synset('new_york.n.02'), Synset('new_york.n.03')]
```

## Does tokens such as zoom_in counts as word?

Depends on what's the definition of a "word", like the example above, if you iterate through the `wn.words()`, you are iterating through the lemma_names and the `new_york` examples shows that multi-word expressions exists in the lemma name lists for each synset.